# Accelerometer to control handstans man?

Tags: corona-sdk

In my game i have to control handstand man using accelerometer.
i used this code:

```
function acc:accelerometer(e)  
        if(e.yGravity > 0.1 and e.yGravity < 0.2)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.1, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > 0.2 and e.yGravity < 0.3)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.2, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > 0.3 and e.yGravity < 0.4)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.3, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > 0.4 and e.yGravity < 0.5)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.4, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > 0.5 and e.yGravity < 0.9)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(0.5, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.1 and e.yGravity < 0.1)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.1, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.2 and e.yGravity < -0.1)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.2, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.3 and e.yGravity < -0.2)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.3, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.4 and e.yGravity < -0.3)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.4, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.5 and e.yGravity < -0.4)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.5, .5, boy.x, boy.y)

    elseif(e.yGravity > -0.9 and e.yGravity < -0.5)then
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(-0.6, .5, boy.x, boy.y)
end
```

please help me how to code.

Comment: Flagged as not a real question. Please try to tell us what you want to do [http://translate.google.com/](http://translate.google.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
function acc:accelerometer(e)
    boy:applyLinearImpulse(e.yGravity, .5, 0, 0)
end
```

This huge if statement looks terrible and is definitely the wrong way to be handling your problem, whatever that is. However, you don't describe your problem at all, you don't explain this code (would like to know what exactly are the parameters for applyLinearImpulse), and this website is not a place to submit chunks of code and expect others to do your work for you. If you want a helpful answer, please ask a helpful question. Good luck.

Comment: i have to increase the force based on the position.same time i have to change the picture for each position.